# UPDATE table's running total and value fields at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I am using sql server for the db and gridview for presentation and editing of data in web page. So on row updating, I need to update the db for both a field that has a numeric value and for running total. There are concurrent updates to this table by multiple users by `uID`.

Can it be achieved using one query... I am quite skeptical about it. So I thought of doing two update queries. But then again, I am worried about performance.

What are my options here?

Table Structure:

```
Id, uID, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Total Val
1,  a2, 2.0,  0.5,  0.1,  0.3,  2.9
2,  b2, 0.1,  0.3,  0.5,  1.0,  1.9
```

EDIT: Total Val column specs

[image]

Comment: If the `Total Val` column is defined as a computed column then it will always contain the correct value and not require any updates

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever nah it isn't the case here and we can't touch the design of this db...

Comment: @bonCodigo Damine's suggestion is the best solution, though. If the `total` column always should be a `SUM` of the values in the other columns, change the column to have a `DEFAULT` value with the formula to do so. That'll prevent you from having to perform regular `UPDATE` statements as it would contain the right value at all times.

Comment: @SchmitzIT for sure it's the best. But some ******* third party ERP software company is having the owenership of this db and there's really no way we can edit the design - that's a *final*, >sigh<. So given that case don't you think I would have to perform an extra update for running total? Or perhaps after update trigger...

Comment: @bonCodigo Both triggers as well as scheduled or ad-hoc updates would have an impact on performance, though. Can't you flag this as a clear bug in the third party's software, though? If the totals field is supposed to be the sum of the other columns, and it isn't showing that, something's wrong in their implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a trigger on table to update the total_val, whenever there is any insert or update operation.

```
            CREATE TRIGGER inserupdate
           ON  triggertestTable
           AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
        AS 
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            update t
            set t.total_val = t.val1+t.val2+t.val3+t.val4
            from triggertestTable t
            inner join inserted i
            on t.uId = i.uId
            inner join updated u
            on u.uId = t.uId

        END
        GO
```